Link Animation Data AND transfer location
I want to replace object A with object B. Both Objects are the Same, just different materials. It is a glass with Ice cubes inside of it. The Cubes are parented to the glass, and the glass is parented to an empty.
I tried to link the parents and the animation data. But whenever I link data, the Object B is changing its location to a completely different position. The animation is transfered but not the locatio.
I already tried to delete all location, rotation and scale with altG altS altR. It didn´t help.
Unfortunately I am not allowed to share files.
Maybe it is a very simple solution, but I can´t find any.
THanks in advance for your help!
